# VueJS Data ForLoop Issue

Tags: vue.js

I'm using forloop to check the items in my data in COMPONENT.

```
{
  data:function(){
    return {
      items:[
       {id:1,name:'John'},
       {id:2,name:'FooBz'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

now I want to check the value first in console in ready hook of my component.

```
{
  .....
 ready:function(){
   console.log(this.items);
   // this return a [__ob__: Observer]
   this.items.forEach(function(x,y){
       ............
   });
 }
}
```

the this.items return a '[**ob**: Observer]' which I can't iterate through because the length of that value is 0 it supposed to be 2.

EDIT:
this is strange on my JSBIN all are working but in my real code its not. Even though I copied my logic from my real code I'm using Laravel Elixir to compile my javascript and 1.0.24 version of Vue.

http://jsbin.com/gijaniqero/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I made a fiddle with your code and it looks fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/rycpctgf/ your problem should be in some other place in your code.

Comment: see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be okay.

Just using your code, i have made demo. It should be okay

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
    <test_component></test_component>
</div>

<template id="test_component">
    <div></div>
</template>

<script src="js/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data: {
        },
        components : {
            'test_component' : {
                template : '#test_component',
                data:function(){
                    return {
                        items:[
                            {id:1,name:'John'},
                            {id:2,name:'FooBz'}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                ready : function(){
                    this.items.forEach(function(x,y){
                        console.log( 'id is : ' +  x.id);
                        console.log( 'name is L ' + x.name);
                        console.log( 'key is ' + y);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```